# Decimales en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
<td>{{results | number:2}}</td>    => esto sale en la vista 120.00
<td>
    <input type="number" ng-model="results" step="any"/>  
    => esto sale en la vista 120
    <input type="number" ng-model="results | number:2" step="any"/>  
    => no sale nada en la vista
</td>
```

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que me salga 120.00 en el input?

Es decir el valor con dos decimales.

Podeis consultar este ejemplo que pasa lo mismo :

https://jsfiddle.net/gsferreira/Lsv9f0b0/

Comment: Buenas, sirdaiz. Quieres que el primer `input` tenga 2 decimales?  y lo intentas en el segundo `input` pero no sale?

Comment: exacto, quiero que en el primer input salga 120.00 pero sale 120 y en el segundo no sale nada

Comment: lo uso en firefox de un pc, en la segundo input me sale un error : 

Error: [ngModel:nonassign] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ngModel/nonassign?p0=results%20%7C%20number%3A2&p1=%3Cinput%20class%3D%22ng-pristine%20ng-untouched%20ng-valid%22%20%22%20step%3D%22any%22%20ng-model%3D%22results%20%7C%20number%3A2%22%20type%3D%22number%22%3E

Comment: Miraré mas tarde a ver si encuentro algo pero ni idea. Mientras tanto, puedes editar la pregunta para añadir ese error que te sale ? ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente librería para obtener el resultado que deseas

[angular-input-masks](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks/)

[demos](http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/)

No se puede utilizar la directiva de number de la manera que deseas ng-model="results | number:2"

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Ahora que lo comenta @cjara. Recuerdo ahora que tuve este problema en un proyecto hace un año o así y efectivamente tuvimos que tirar de máscara para hacerlo. Y por cierto tuvimos que montar un arco de iglesia bastante peculiar. Así que me temo que va a estar en lo cierto.

Comment: el problema de eso es que es text, realizo calculo con los valores que hay dentro, tendria que parsear todos los campos antes de realizar el calculo

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, te dejo el enlace del ejemplo actualizado y funcionando. 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lsv9f0b0/1832/

He puesto los `ng-model="$scope.myDecimal"` y funciona correctamente.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario, pero en el ejmplo que he dejado, si cambias: $scope.myDecimal = 10.00 y le das a run sigue saliendo 10 en el input sin decimales, en tu ejemplo en el primer input si pongo 10,00 en el segundo input q esta desabilitado sale 10

Comment: Acabo de ver que los "0" no los está cogiendo como debería si.

Comment: efectivamente ese es mi problema

Comment: has actulizado? porque me sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, no manejo angularJS y espero que mi respuesta no sea del todo inutil, pero según el ejemplo de jsfiddle, y si observas, el segundo `input`es de tipo `text` y tiene `disable=true`, y el segundo tuyo es de tipo `number`. El tipo `text` del segundo input del ejemplo debería facilitar que el pipe refleje los dos decimales.

Podrías intentar con un tipo `text` en el input y usar una regex para validar ese campo en caso de que el usuario lo pueda/deba modificar y no ingrese solo números, o buscar alguna directiva de angular que actualice la propiedad `value` del campo (un `ng-value` o algo así).

`<input type=number step="0.01" value="120.00"></input>`

Interesante tu pregunta, estaré pendiente si alguien logra resolverlo. Saludos